# <Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded>　Is there anyone who can solve the problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After submitting the form, I want to refresh the form's contents. Please teach me following the problem.

```js
scroll_bottom = function() {
  if ($('#messages').length > 0) {
    $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
  }
}

submit_message = function() {
  $('#message_body').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $('#submit').click();
      e.target.value = "";
    };
  });
};

submit_button = function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    $('button').click();
    e.target.value = "";
  });
};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  $('.message .close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').transition('fade');
  });
  submit_button();
  submit_message();
  scroll_bottom();
});
```

Comment: Refresh based on what?

Comment: The problem is because you're creating an infinite cycle of events. In the click handler for `#submit` you trigger a click event on *every button in the DOM*, which causes another click on `#submit` which raises another click event on *every button in the DOM*... and so on. Don't do that

Comment: timotgl >> after pushing the submit button, i want to clear text of the form..

Comment: Rory McCrossan >> thanks but i have no idea about what section i have to edit in this code.. can you let me know that?

Comment: why so much functions and event fired just to submit form and clear inputs. Short code can also work

Answer (score 0):

That means your call stack has overflowed.  Something is triggering itself over and over.

```
submit_button = function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    $('button').click();
    e.target.value = "";
  });
};
```

When you click on `#submit` all buttons are being clicked which will click `#submit` again and again, and this will lead to an infinite loop and fill up the call stack.

Comment: thanks. that's why i have to delete the above code right?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.  At least removing `$('button').click();` should fix the error you were getting after clicking `#submit`.